# Pandas: convert items to dict where orderID is the dict key

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of orders and items. Some orders have more than 1 item.

```
Orderid, Itemid
1       123
2       122
2       234
3       334
4       111
4       998
4       110
```

I have read them into a dataframe. How can I reshape the dataframe, or use python to get my data like this:

```
Orderid: [itemid, itemid, ....]
Orderid: [itemid, itemid, ....]
Orderid: [itemid, itemid, ....]
Orderid: [itemid, itemid, ....]
```

What I have tried: create a dict whose keys are all empty lists, then add to each key the list of related values. It does not seem to work though as mydict.values() are still empty lists after running this.

```
for order in df['Order']:
    mydict[order] = []

for order in df['Order']:
    if order == mydict[order]:
        mydict[order].append(df['Item'])
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that?  In many cases it is better to leave it in the format you have and do whatever operations you need to do by grouping on orderid.

Comment: Trying to apply the apriori algorithm (frequent item set) and need to have the items going column-wise in my dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
>>> df.groupby('Orderid').Itemid.apply(list)
Orderid
1              [123]
2         [122, 234]
3              [334]
4    [111, 998, 110]
Name: Itemid, dtype: object
```

Note that working with DataFrames whose contents are container types (like lists) can sometimes produce unexpected results.  If possible it is often smoother to keep your data separated by row and do the calculations you need to do by aggregating via `groupby`.

Comment: BrenBarn - any obvious way to also push each item into the next empty column, rather than generate the list?

Comment: @JeffreyJames: What do you want in the "empty" columns?  That sounds like it would be creating a non-tabular structure, which isn't really a good fit for pandas.  Also, it will become quite inefficient if your groups have widely varying sizes (since some rows will have a lot of empty elements).

Comment: Good point @BrenBarn - after df.to_csv'ing the data, the format is actually workable once I lose the list chars [ and ] (which is fine). I'll try to run the analysis now. Thanks again for your assist. All the attempts using vstack, unstack and melt got me nowhere :)